# В чем причина ошибки std@bad_function_call при создании потока

Tags: c++, многопоточность, функции, lambda

Есть следующий код:

```
std::function<void()> f=[](){std::cout<<"Yaha";};

std::thread thr1(f);
std::thread thr2(f); //Здесь возникает ошибка std@bad_function_call
```

Прошу подсказать причину возникновения данной ошибки. Как я понимаю объект f становится пустым (не пойму почему).

И второй вопрос:

```
void thr1_f()
 {
  std::cout<<"Yaha"; 
 }
```

в чем разница в std::thread(thr1_f) и std::thread(&thr1_f) и когда какой вариант следует использовать? Почему нельзя вызвать std::thread(&f) (а нужно использовать std::thread(std::ref(f))?

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Сильно сомневаюсь, что `std::cout` поддерживает конкурентный доступ из разных потоков

Comment: Приведенный обрывок кода не компилируется, а даже если дописать нужные заголовочные файлы, то он не будет выдавать заявленной ошибки. @AntonShchyrov тем не менее, он поддерживает.

Comment: Ошибка возникает при сборке указанного кода в Embarcadero RAD Studio (C++ Builder), в MSVS 2019 ошибки действительно нет.

Answer (score 1):

[std@bad_function_call](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bad_function_call) можно получить, если внутри фукнции лежит `nullptr`.

Смотрим снова в [документацию](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) и видим такое

```
template< class Function, class... Args > 
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

ага, нужно, что бы move конструктор отработал и можно получить такой эффект. Так как автор вопроса упоминает о передаче по ссылке и по std::ref, сделаем маленький шаг в сторону

```
std::function<void()> f=[](){std::cout<<"Yaha";};

std::thread thr1(std::move(f));
std::thread thr2(f); 
thr1.join();
thr2.join();
```

и получим желаемую ошибочку. `std::move` провоцирует вызов move конструктора, который в случае `std::function` зануляет указатель.

А возможно, компилятор у  Embarcadero RAD Studio такой хитрый, что вызывает move конструктор. или там сам `std::thread` объявлен с `std::forward`, надо смотреть в сам код. я этого проверить не могу.

Comment: из заголовочного файла RAD Studio                                                                                           
                'template<class _Fn,
  class... _Types,
  class = enable_if_t<!is_same<typename decay<_Fn>::type, thread>::value> >
  explicit thread(_Fn&& _Fx, _Types&&... _Args)
  { // construct with _Fx(_Args...)
  _Launch(&_Thr,
   _STD make_unique<tuple<decay_t<_Fn>, decay_t<_Types>...> >(
    _STD forward<_Fn>(_Fx), _STD forward<_Types>(_Args)...));
  }'

Comment: о, и минусатор и сюда подъехал:) молодец минусатор, так и дальше делай!